# How do I append a blank value to a Python list?

Tags: python

I'm trying to append a blank value to a Python list. Another value will eventually be added after that blank value as well.

This works:

```
foo=['NYC', 'Ny', 'Us']
print foo 
#['NYC', 'Ny', 'Us']

foo.append('')
print foo 
#['NYC', 'Ny', 'Us','']

foo.append('TRUE')
print foo
#['NYC', 'Ny', 'Us','', 'TRUE']
```

As you can see, all the values are essentially strings.

How do I make the first append a blank value without the quotes? I would rather have nothing if it's empty since I'll be passing this list eventually into a file and into a database.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  The quote marks are just there to show where the string begins and ends.  They are not part of the string itself.

Comment: Regardless, I want it to be basically emtpy, so two commas in a row. Don't want to add extra, unneeded complexity and characters

Comment: It can't be that empty. Unless you're working with a few hundred GB of data, I wouldn't worry about the extra "complexity and characters" of `None` or `''`.

Comment: You can only store python objects in a list. In python, everything is an object, but `nothing` is not an object, and thus you can't have an empty slot in a list.

Comment: by any chance, do you want to transform this into a CSV file?

Comment: @miraculixx: Solution looking for problem?

Comment: @martineau no, just a hunch regarding _Don't want to add extra, unneeded complexity and characters_. sounds like we're not talking about the print statement because, well, who cares. However if the ultimate goal is a CSV file all of a sudden the OPs request starts to make some sense (think `foo.py > some/file`).

Comment: Yeah, I'm outputting to a CSV file. Shoulda made that more clear. I'm actually simply using the `csv` module's `writerow` method

Comment: simplycoding: In that case you should probably accept @turbulencetoo's answer because the output from  `csv.writer.writerow(foo)` following `foo.append(BlankObj())` and `foo.append('TRUE')` would be `NYC,Ny,Us,,TRUE` using it. If you add the `BlankObj = BlankObj()` I suggested, you could just use `foo.append(BlankObj)`.

Comment: How is that better than appending `NULL`?

Answer (score 4):

Interestingly, you could define a custom class with a `__repr__` method that would give you what you want. `__repr__` defines the way an opject will be represented when printed as part of a container such as a list.

```
>>> class BlankObj:
...  def __repr__(self):
...   return ""
...
>>> list((1,2,BlankObj(),3))
[1, 2, , 3]
```

This is purely academic though; it's not saving any space compared to just having a `None` in your list. A `None` object would be the best representation that a slot is empty.

Comment: I'd make `BlankObj` a singleton with `BlankObj = BlankObj()` which would make using it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The quotes are not part of the actual value in the list, so when you append `""` -- and it shows as `''` -- what is in the list is a zero-length string.

If instead of a zero length string you want "nothing", the python value `None` is the closest thing to "nothing".

The choice depends on what you mean by "blank value". For me, that's an empty string. `None`, however, is good if you need to distinguish between an empty string and "nothing".

Answer (score -2):

An empty string is represented by `''` in Python.

When you pass it into the database, it should eventually end up as a blank string as well.

For example :

```
print ''
```

will print a completely blank line

Comment: Actually, it won't technically print a blank line. It'll print a line with a single character on it - a linefeed.

Comment: I interpret the line `\n` as a blank line - to me at least, that's what makes it a line!

Comment: But that's about the behaviour of `print`, not the behaviour of `''`.

Comment: Well, you did say that it would print a completely blank line... and it isn't. And the way you're interpreting `\n` is different from the way Python would interpret it. If you redirected a bunch of `print ''` (or just `print`) statements to a file, you'd end up with several "blank" lines. Open that back up with Python and try iterating over the file and checking `if line:`. Python will think the lines aren't empty.

Comment: What do you define as a blank line, then? The absence of a line?

Comment: A blank line has no characters in it. You obviously can't have one in the middle of a text file, but you can have one at the end. If you write `'1\n2\n\n4\n'` to a file, the third line appears "blank" but has a linefeed on it. The very last line (below `4`) really is blank. The linefeed on the previous line creates this last line, and then no characters are present on it.

Comment: The Python style guide disagrees with your assertion that you cannot have a blank line in the middle of a file: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#blank-lines

Comment: That's a totally different thing. That link is referring to _style_ for Python source code, using "blank line" to mean a line with nothing apparently on it (it's shorter than "a line with nothing other than whitespace"). A Python source code "blank line" can have just a linefeed, or it can have a bunch of spaces and then a linefeed. If you read in such a file, however, you will find that the "blank line" _has characters in it_.